# Position span to hang over the relative parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to position a span so that it will be above it's sibling and "hang over" or be positioned on top of it's parent. The parent is relatively positioned.

Please view my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bflemi3/aNkSw/) to get the whole picture

What it currently looks like...

[image]

This is what I want it to look like...
[image]

The span (tooltip):

```
.grid-window span.validation-message:after {
    border-color: #F2DEDE transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 8px;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    width: 0;
}
.grid-window span.validation-message {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F2DEDE;
    border: 1px solid #EED3D7;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.098);
    color: #B94A48;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 20px;
    left: 263px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.098);
    top: -26px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

The parent element:

```
element.style {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    left: 488px;
    outline: 0 none;
    top: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    z-index: 1002;
}
.ui-dialog {
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0.2em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
}
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by Rohrbs, if I explicitly set the width of the span (tooltip) then it will indeed hang over the form. But this isn't practical since each tooltip could potentially display a different message. So my question now becomes - **How can I set the width to be dynamic and still have the span (tooltip) hang over the form?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style your `.grid-window .control-group .controls` to be `position: relative;` then only your absolute positioned `.grid-window span.validation-message` will work as you want.

See **[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aNkSw/19/)**

**Update**
You wanted to be your tool-tip width variable so I have replaced the `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` in `.grid-window span.validation-message` and added `left: 175px; top: -25px; float: left;` and also `min-width: 0; max-width: 500px;` width: auto; also work. to make this work as you want. Note to float is a must else it won't work.

So, main changes **(most important part)** are `float: left; position: relative;` to `.grid-window span.validation-message` and also you need not to declare `position: relative;` to `.grid-window .control-group .controls`

See **[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aNkSw/20/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you manually set the `width` in the class `.grid-window span.validation-message` to say `width: 50%;` it will hang over the edge like you want. You will just have to keep the message short enough to ensure proper fitment.

Comment: I updated my question. It seems that I wasn't being clear what I'm looking to do.

Comment: Ahhh! I see. Hang "off" the dialog window.

Comment: If you manually set the width of that `span` to say `width: 50%;` it will hang over the edge like you want. You'll just have to keep the message short enough to ensure proper fitment. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This kind of works. Is there a way to do this without having to specify the width? Text inside the tooltip will be variable in length

Comment: You should also update your answer to reflect changing the parent div's `overflow` to visible. I think you had that originally

Answer (score 0):

On the `.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content` DIV just change the overflow from auto to visible, and it will help

Comment: I've updated as instructed but it still won't overlap the form itself and "hang over" the form. It hangs over the header which is good though, but not quite there. Here's the update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bflemi3/aNkSw/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve your issue with only minor changes to your CSS and HTML(class names).

You can see the results via your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aNkSw/16/

I added a different class for each span, and tweaked only this CSS bit to:

```
.grid-window span.validation-message-id:after, .grid-window span.validation-message-name:after {
    border-color: #F2DEDE transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 8px;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -16px;
    left: 10px;
}
.grid-window span.validation-message-id {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F2DEDE;
    border: 1px solid #EED3D7;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.098);
    color: #B94A48;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -81px 0 0 0;
    left: 292px;
    z-index: 99;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.098);
    width: 200px;
}
.grid-window span.validation-message-name {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F2DEDE;
    border: 1px solid #EED3D7;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.098);
    color: #B94A48;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -41px 0 0 0;
    left: 292px;
    z-index: 99;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.098);
    width: 200px;
}
```

I can't say I agree with how you coded the whole thing though.

Comment: Most of the html/css/classes are from jquery ui so, but the tooltip is my creation. You said you didn't agree with how it was coded, can you explain more about how you would go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Since most of the html/css are from jquery UI, then I take that back. It's just that the code in the fiddle looks cluttered, unnecessary rules, so-on and so-forth. Just by comparing the updated fiddle, you can already see what I removed just from the rules. Due to time consumption, I can't re-write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you could use an extra element here's a solution I use a lot for this kind of positioning:
HTML:

```
<div class="validation-message-wrapper">
<span class="validation-message" style="">Please enter a number</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.validation-message-wrapper {
    width:0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 70px;
    top: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

The clue is to create a zero size reference point ( the `.validation-message-wrapper` ) position it where you want and then position your element in relation to it.

Here's a working demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/aNkSw/22/)

I also did some other minor CSS changes just to tune it a bit:

```
 .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    padding: 0.4em 1em;
    position: relative;
}

.grid-window span.validation-message:after {
    border-color: #F2DEDE transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 8px;
    content:"";
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -16px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
.grid-window span.validation-message {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F2DEDE;
    border: 1px solid #EED3D7;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.098);
    color: #B94A48;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: auto;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.098);
    margin-top: -40px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

I hope that helps.

If you'd like something more generic I've made a jQuery tooltip plugin ([tipy](http://www.xpy.gr/tipy)) which is pretty easy to use and implement.

Comment: I'd still have to set a width though. Ideally I'd like to not have to set the width, or at least have a max width so that the tooltips are variable in size and fit their innerText.

Comment: @bflemi3 You don't need to set a width, the width is set to the demo only beacause you've set it in your example.

Comment: But if I remove the width from `.grid-window span.validation-message` then the tooltip scrunches up to about 50px. Try it...